# php: failing when including a file that is defined in an array

Tags: php, mysql

I want to include a file, based on a value I get from my database. Inside class page in page.php I have this function to get the data I want :

```
function getPage(){
    $page=array(
      'title'=>$this->title,
        'content'=>$this->content,
        'module'=>$this->module
    );
    return $page;
}
```

And in pageview.php I call it like this : `$elements=$page->getPage();`
The function works just fine and I get my content , which I can manipulate like this for example(I know heredox is not the way to go but please ignore it, it's not the problem) :

```
 echo <<<EOT
    <div class='row-fluid'>
    <H1> title:$elements[title]</H1></br>
    $elements[content]
    $elements[module]
    </div>
EOT;
```

Now here comes the problem. I have a function called includeModule, which is like this :

```
function includeModule($page){

    $page=strtolower($page);

    if(file_exists("modules/".$page."php")) include("/modules/".$page."php");
    else Echo "No such Module Exists :".$page." </br>";

}
```

Now lets say I want to include a page named "tax.php". If I use `include("/modules/tax.php)";` it works just fine. If I try though to use `include("/modules/".$elements[module].".php)";` it does nothing ( an yes $elements[module] does contain only the word  "tax" ).
I even tried assigning the value of $elements[module] to another variable but nothing.

The strangest part of all is that if I try to use my function ( includeModule), even if I manually set the $page variable to "tax", it still doe not include anything and says that the file does not exist ( even though it does) ?

Any help on this ?

edit: i already tried removing the / but if i do it includes nothing again

edit: i've change the function a litle so i can get some feedback

```
if(file_exists("modules/".$page.".php")){
        echo "<p>file exists</p>";
        include("modules/".$page."**.**php");
    }else{
        echo getcwd();
         Echo "<p>No such Module Exists :".$page."</p>";
    }
```

OK solved. thanks for all the answers. By my mistake the trailing slash as well as the dot right before the php extension were left out . thanks for helping :)

Comment: You're using relative paths so it's going to depend on the current working directory to find your files (in addition to your include_path). You can check to make sure it's correct and what you're expecting by using the `getcwd()` function.

Comment: `modules/page.php != /modules/page.php`! (well, probably not anyway) Check your absolute path

Comment: $elements[module] Quote your array keys correctly too, $elements['module'] to avoid nasty errors.

Comment: @Cups `$elements[module]` is correct when including in a parsed string (but nowhere else).

Comment: Well, I will go away and look that up, new on me! Cheers.  ps here is a reference in case anyone else makes the same error as me http://oreilly.com/catalog/progphp/chapter/ch05.html

Comment: I only found out this week, I always concat, it's easier to read

Comment: (I edited my previous comment) I always concat too, but that makes it more typo prone.  Good trick, good thread. Thx!

Comment: i already checked with getcwd() and i know the directory is right ( is right under c:/www/dev/site). The folder modules exists under c:/www/dev/site/modules. i just down understand why it cant find the file when it's already there 0.o . I added the leading / in both now but nothing .
Also thanks for the tip @popnoodles

Comment: **Adding** a leading `/` is not going to work because the modules aren't at `c:/modules/`

Comment: thanks :) hahah i have to say that i've learned my lessons for today :P ( one of them is when you're tired take a small break off work to concentrate better and you will avoid stupid mistakes :P)

Answer (score 1):

> if i use include("modules/tax.php)"; it works just fine.

In your code, you're using

```
include("/modules/".$page."php");
         ^-- Note the leading /
```

Try removing the `/`

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing if `"modules/".$page."php"` exists but trying to include `"/modules/".$page."php"` which are probably not the same things (notice the leading `/` on the latter).

```
if(file_exists("modules/".$page."php")) include("modules/".$page."php");
```

Answer (score 0):

OK ive solved it thanks guys:) each answer was helpfull :) ( the answer was a combination of your answers+a litle more atttention needed from me . I forgot the . right before the php extension .. lolz.. guess when you are tired you have to take a litle break off word in order to be able to concetrate right ). thanks again guys :)